# Get Entities from DB using generics and EF

Tags: entity-framework

We've created an azure sql DB using EF code first.
Let's say we have 3 entities/tables Students, classes, teachers.
We would like to implement a method like this:
T GetEntity(ket int), that gets an entity by key from one of the tables accourding to T.
Is it possible at all?
TX Tal

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Do you also have an idea for:             'T GetEntity(string property, string value)', which finds the first value where T.Property = value. May be you have a better idea of how to implement a generic function that gets entities by property name and it's value.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

```
var student = context.Set<Student>().Find(1);
```

Comment: please keep in mind that Find first check local context. If you want to force loading use `where(x => x.Id == 1)`. In this case you may have an interface (for example `IHasId { int Id}`) to constrain your type parameter T in the generic method prototype, or you may use reflexion on T to build the where predicate.